# Cron with notify-send

Tags: linux, cron, notify, notify-send

I need to show a notification from a cron job. My crontab is something like:

```
$ crontab -l
# m h  dom mon dow   command
  * *   *   *   *    Display=:0.0 /usr/bin/notify-send Hey "How are you"
```

I checked `/var/log/syslog` and the command is actually executed every minute but it doesn't pop up the notification.
Can anybody help me understand why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
$ crontab -l
# m h  dom mon dow   command
  * *   *   *   *    export DISPLAY=:0.0 && export XAUTHORITY=/home/ravi/.Xauthority && sudo -u ravi /usr/bin/notify-send Hey "How are you"
```

Comment: Just adding "export DISPLAY=:0.0" did the trick for me. That said, the cronjob is running under my user account. XAUTHORITY is probably need when run from a different account than the one where the popup needs to appear. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me too (I didn't need to use "sudo")

Comment: Me too. I could reduce this command to `* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && notify-send Hey "How are you"`

Comment: It can be further reduced to `* * * * * DISPLAY=:0.0 notify-send Hey "How are you"`

Comment: @DrunkenMaster I just tried this on 18.04; worked for me.  The crontab is my own (not root's)  `*   * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && notify-send -t 10000 Hey Hey`

Comment: This doesn't work on Ubuntu 21 but this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53598510/10633734 answer by Mr. Goferito does

Answer (score 121):

I use i3 on Ubuntu 18.04. My way to solve this is:

`* * * * *  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) notify-send Hey "this is dog!"`

Edit 2020: I still use it on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Can confirm this works on Ubuntu 18.04 where the accepted answer did not.

Comment: Can confirm this works on Ubuntu 20.04 when the confirmed answer did not.

Comment: This should be the confirmed answer now. I subconsciously went straight to the accepted answer which didn't work, and therefore initially missed the working solution.

Comment: More information: https://askubuntu.com/questions/872792/what-is-xdg-runtime-dir

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: I need to add <username> after cron express to make it work, or it will error `Error: bad username; while reading /etc/crontab`

Comment: Can confirm this works on Ubuntu 22.04 when the confirmed answer did not.

Comment: Worked for me on Pop!_OS

Comment: this is working for me on ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Works also on Ubuntu 23.04

Answer (score 7):

In Ubuntu 14.04 exporting the display did not work for me.  Below is a cron script I'm using to shutdown a virtual machine when a laptop's battery state becomes too low.  The line setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is the modification that finally got the warnings working correctly.

```
#!/bin/bash

# if virtual machine is running, monitor power consumption
if pgrep -x vmware-vmx; then

  bat_path="/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/"

  if [ -e "$bat_path" ]; then

    bat_status=$(cat $bat_path/status)

    if [ "$bat_status" == "Discharging" ]; then

      bat_current=$(cat $bat_path/capacity)

      # halt vm if critical; notify if low
      if [ "$bat_current" -lt 10 ]; then

        /path/to/vm/shutdown/script
        echo "$( date +%Y.%m.%d_%T )" >> "/home/user/Desktop/VM Halt Low Battery"

        elif [ "$bat_current" -lt 15 ]; then
        eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ)";
        notify-send -i "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/status/24/battery-caution.svg"  "Virtual machine will halt when battery falls below 10% charge."

      fi

    fi

  fi

fi

exit 0
```

The relevant line is here:

```
eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ)";
```

I found the solution here: https://askubuntu.com/a/346580/255814

Comment: I use archlinux, which uses a different process for the gnome-session, but still with the string `gnome-session` as a long flag. Thus needed to add `-f` to the `pgrep` invocation.

Answer (score 6):

Only this works for me (Xubuntu)

```
eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME xfce4-session)/environ)"; notify-send  "hello world"
```

If you are in gnome enviroment, you need change `xfce4-session` to `gnome-session`

refer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/298608/notify-send-doesnt-work-from-crontab

Comment: As of ubuntu 17.10 I believe you need to be looking for `gdm-x-session`. Here's the line I used: `eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gdm-x-session)/environ)"`

Answer (score 6):

add `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` ：

`* * * * * DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus /usr/bin/notify-send 'helloworld..' 'msg...'`

Answer (score 3):

Work for me on fedora 22:

Put this line in the .sh script before notify-send get called:

```
eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ)"
```

Answer (score 2):

On recent Ubuntu versions, the following should work.

```
#notify_me.sh, can be placed e.g. in your home directory

#!/bin/bash
eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ)";
# the actual notification
DISPLAY=:0 notify-send "Notify me!"
```

Then you add a line to your user's cronjobs via `crontab` as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and reduced answer:

```
01 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && notify-send Hey "How are you"
```

If you need `Xauthority` permission, here's a generalizable form using the `$LOGNAME` variable

```
01 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && && export XAUTHORITY=/home/$LOGNAME/.Xauthority notify-send Hey "How are you"
```

As pointed out by @tripleee, there's no real need for sudo here

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [nmax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519673/cron-with-notify-send/41997565#answer-26477523) above, I also solved the issue by setting `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable.
However, I am using a combination of Linux Mint 19 (xfce4) and XMonad and for some reason, I don't have the process `xfce4-session` running. Instead, I found that `xfce4-terminal` is (usually) running, which resulted in the following line in the beginning of my script:

```
eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME xfce4-terminal)/environ)"
```

This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I created a /usr/bin script that uses the DISPLAY-:0.0 technique http://pastebin.com/h11p2HtN

It doesn't take XAUTHORITY into account.  I'll have to investigate that further.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issue that your notify-send script is working fine locally but it is not working with cron jobs then use this command. and replace "saurav" with your username.

```
sudo -u saurav DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus notify-send "Your message goes here"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was with using `root` user with `notify-send`. I realized this when I saw that `sudo notify-send` didn't work on the terminal but just `notify-send` (i.e. with current user) did.
So instead of editing the usual `/etc/crontab` which is used by `root`, I had a custom cron script created for  `myusername`. Please check my whole answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/710326/534253).

Answer (score 0):

Under Manjaro (Arch), I had to do this:

Figure out the value of `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`:

```
$ echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
```

Edit the crontab file (`crontab -e`):

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"

* * * * * /path/to/script_that_calls_notify-send.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

May be you can try:

`* *   *   *   *    env DISPLAY=:0.0 sudo -u ravi /usr/bin/notify-send Hey "How are you"`

Comment: Downvote: The cron job will already be running as `ravi` so the `sudo` is not adding anything useful here.

Answer (score -3):

Try this when you call `notify-send` in your script:

`echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -u USER notify-send "your alert message"`