# Crontab of python script using notify-send

Tags: python, cron

This is my python script for notify send:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import os
mstr='The scoreis 102/3'
title="SCORE"
os.environ.setdefault('DISPLAY', ':0.0')
os.system('notify-send -i "notification-message-IM" "'+title+'" "'+mstr+'"')
```

It works normally when I run the script,but while trying to run it from cron it is not working

I have tried reference from this links:
[Cron scheduler of python script using notify-send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174784/cron-scheduler-of-python-script-using-notify-send)

[Cron with notify-send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519673/cron-with-notify-send/16520076#16520076)

Even in crontab i have tried to run a notify-send command like this:

```
* *  *   *   * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && /usr/bin/notify-send "How are you"
```

But of no help.

Is there anything I am doing wrong please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using a little bit different code, but the end result is what you were trying to achieve: get `notify-send` to work from a python script via `crontab`.

Here's my Python 3.x script:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['notify-send', 'Running.'])
```

And here's how I setup `crontab`:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0
XAUTHORITY=/home/matrix/.Xauthority
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/path/to/my/script.py
```

This should work with Ubuntu 16.04 and python3, I cannot speak for other OS's, but you can give it a try. Use `which` to check the path of your `python` or `python3` installation.

By the time I finished this answer the "Running." notification popped up at least 3 times.

Comment: Works fine, just may want to clarify that the the home directory needs to be adapted to the user name.